# libmongoc issue about update none existence record?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using this driver to communicate with mongod,I found updating an nonexistence document with $inc operator,it returns success,while actually there is no document has been updated.Is this a bug or an intended behavior?

The mongod response with nModified == 0 && ok == 1.

The following is the tcpdump response from mongod.

```
0x0000:  4500 007b ec2d 4000 4006 504d 7f00 0001  E..{.-@.@.PM....
0x0010:  7f00 0001 6989 a01b ae5a 275b de9c c127  ....i....Z'[...'
0x0020:  8018 0180 fe6f 0000 0101 080a 1bcf a93e  .....o.........>
0x0030:  1bcf a93d 4700 0000 eb1b 0000 7f00 0000  ...=G...........
0x0040:  0100 0000 0800 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
0x0050:  0000 0000 0100 0000 2300 0000 106f 6b00  ........#....ok.
0x0060:  0100 0000 106e 4d6f 6469 6669 6564 0000  .....nModified..
0x0070:  0000 0010 6e00 0000 0000 00              ....n......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,I found that I can fetch the mongod response with mongoc_collection_get_last_error.And I can tell weather it updates some records or no record has been updated with that.

Comment: Is this solution sufficient for your needs, or is there still an open question?